# "Field Name was not found in the send source"

Tags: exacttarget, ampscript

I'm a bit new to ExactTarget in general so I apologize if this has already been answered (if it has, I can't find it anywhere).

I am attempting to create an email which will conditionally display n of 50 bulleted lists containing links to product information. However, whenever I attempt to send this email, I receive the following error message:

```
Other errors found in the email.
Category: AMP Script

Functions and Custom Objects:('
  Field Name %%F50%% was not found in the send source.
 Category: AMP Script
```

The second paragraph of the error message is repeated 50 times total (one for each field).

I cannot seem to figure-out why this issue is occurring:

- I have a Data Extension with data for each field mapped in it.
- I have imported valid data from a CSV to the data extension.
- I have a list of valid subscribers to whom I am attempting to distribute.
- I have an email template with custom areas inside each of which check if the subscriber has a "true" value for each field and shows/hides the content snippets on that basis.
- I have 50x content snippets (one for each field).

There has to be something I'm missing here. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the 50 fields are not in your sending data extension, you'll need to retrieve them with a script something like this.  Note the values are displayed with`%%=v(@DEColumn1)=%%`:

```
%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @lookupValue, @i

set @lookupValue = "whee"
set @numRowsToReturn = 0 /* 0 means all */
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("DataExtensionName",@numRowsToReturn,"DEColumn1 desc, DEColumn2 asc","LookupColumn", @lookupValue)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

var @DEColumn1, @DEColumn2
set @row = row(@rows,@i) /*get row based on loop counter */
set @DEColumn1 = field(@row,"DEColumn1")
set @DEColumn2 = field(@row,"DEColumn2")

]%%

Row %%=v(@i)=%%, DEColumn1 is %%=v(@DEColumn1)=%%, DEColumn2 is %%=v(@DEColumn2)=%%

%%[ next @i ]%%

%%[ else ]%%

No rows found

%%[ endif ]%%
```

Also, there are a lot more people answering SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com) -- mostly tagged with [marketing-cloud](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud), [ampscript](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ampscript).